# Umbraco Database .Fetch<>() code error - SQL, C#, ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, linq, umbraco

I have some code on a project I am looking at which is using the folllowing SQL:

```
List<RoomAllotmentViewModel> listRoomAllotment = db.Fetch<RoomAllotmentViewModel>
                    (
                        "SELECT Id" +
                        ", CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),[Year],0) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),[Month],0) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),[Date],0),120) AllotmentDate" +
                        ", RoomTypeId" +
                        ", (SELECT RoomType FROM RoomType R WHERE A.RoomTypeid = R.Id) RoomTypeName" +
                        ", (Alloted - Booked) Available" +
                        ", Price" +
                        " FROM Room_Allotment A" +
                        " WHERE" +
                        " CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),[Year],0) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),[Month],0) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),[Date],0),120) >= '" + startDay.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'" +
                        " AND CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),[Year],0) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),[Month],0) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),[Date],0),120) < '" + endDay.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'" +
                        " ORDER BY AllotmentDate, RoomTypeId");
```

The model is not an entity class:

```
public class RoomAllotmentViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime AllotmentDate { get; set; }
    public int RoomTypeId { get; set; }
    public string RoomTypeName { get; set; }
    public int Available { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
}
```

There are entity classes for the RoomType and Room_Allotment tables:

```
[TableName("RoomType")]
[PrimaryKey("Id", autoIncrement = true)]
[ExplicitColumns]
public class RoomType
{
    [Column]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide RoomType", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string RoomType { get; set; }
}


[TableName("Room_Allotment")]
[PrimaryKey("Id", autoIncrement = true)]
public class Room_Allotment
{
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Date { get; set; }
    public int RoomTypeId { get; set; }
    public int Alloted { get; set; }
    public int Booked { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
}
```

Currently I get the following exception running the project:

> A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type
>   'System.Reflection.RuntimeModule'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: A circular
>   reference was detected while serializing an object of type
>   'System.Reflection.RuntimeModule'.
>
> [InvalidOperationException: A circular reference was detected while
>   serializing an object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeModule'.]
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)
>   +2616    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)
>   +371    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeCustomObject(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +819
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)
>   +2834    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)
>   +371    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeEnumerable(IEnumerable
>   enumerable, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +186
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)
>   +2782    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)
>   +371    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeCustomObject(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +819
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)
>   +2834    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)
>   +371    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeCustomObject(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +819
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)
>   +2834    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)
>   +371    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeCustomObject(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +819
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)
>   +2834    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)
>   +371    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeCustomObject(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +819
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)
>   +2834    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)
>   +371    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeCustomObject(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +819
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)
>   +2834    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)
>   +371    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object
>   obj, StringBuilder output, SerializationFormat serializationFormat)
>   +57    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object
>   obj, SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +83
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object
>   obj) +44    System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext
>   context) +325
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.b__17()
>   +23    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter
>   filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +242
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19()
>   +21    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter
>   filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +242
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.b__19()
>   +21    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter
>   filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +242
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19()
>   +21    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +175
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.b__20()
>   +89    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.b__22(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +102    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
>   +57    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +43
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +14
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +23    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +57
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +23    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +25
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +23    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +47    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +9651688    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Variables for the startDay and endDay are:

```
var startDay = DateTime.ParseExact(arrival, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var endDay = DateTime.ParseExact(departure, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The values of these variables in the exception above are:

```
startDay: {30/08/2015 00:00:00}
endDay: {31/08/2015 00:00:00}
```

"db" and its methods is: `ApplicationContext.Current.DatabaseContext.Database;` which is part of the Umbraco Core library.

Apologies in advance for any excess info. Essentially my questions are:

- Why is the exception is happening?
- Is there a LINQ solution for this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this exception is most likely happening because you are getting an exception in executing that query. What happens after the first exception is that it tries to serialize this exception object with a JSON serializer, causing the circular reference exception that you actually see up there.

So what you need to do is to actually find the initial exception and solve the problem causing it to happen.

I would take a look at the logs in `/App_Data/Logs/` and see if there's any clues on what exception is actually happening in the first place. It could be something really simple - it just blows up even when trying to serialize the most simple exceptions as the complex structure of an exception object is not serializable with out-of-the-box serializer settings.

If you need a more viable solution in the long run, I believe it is possible to create an ExceptionConverter and have it registrered in the list of converters used by the serializer. This would then need to serialize the actual exception message so you can actually see what the error is instead of getting that circular exception. This is however not something I've done in an umbraco solution, so you might need to Google a bit.